# How to get UserProfile from Gmail API?

Tags: java, email, gmail, gmail-api

I want to get current state of users mailbox (HistoryId) so that any new mails after that state are synced.

As per Google API [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile) tried it over their it returns following fields

```
{
  "emailAddress": string,
  "messagesTotal": integer,
  "threadsTotal": integer,
  "historyId": unsigned long
}
```

As my code is in java i tried it their but it returns only the userId

Code :

```
service.users().getProfile(user);
```

service is the Gmail authenticated service object and user is userId

API reference : [=>](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/Gmail.Users.GetProfile.html)

Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following to retrieve all the information as specified above:

Once you have imported this class reference:

```
com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Profile
```

Then it exposes the following methods when you instantiate the object.
I would think it is something in the line of (incomplete code - only indication):

```
Profile.getEmailAddress();

Profile.getMessagesTotal(); 
Profile.getThreadsTotal(); 
Profile.getHistoryId();
```

[**Gmail Profile class**](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/model/Profile.html)

Comment: all authorization and authentication is done. I am facing a split behaviour of getProfile, on GoogleAPI try it ,it works fine and using java code it return just the userId